# Use gulp to copy part of a text/html file?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm looking for something like gulp-html-replace but instead of replacing what's in between the

Will be useful for modifying html documents.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking the wrong question. If you have a consistent part (content) present in multiple html documents, you should be using a server side language to generate the html pages. That way you can create partials and modularize them to be included in multiple pages so when you change it once the change can be reflected.

If this is somehow not an option (for whatever reason) you should consider looking at something like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Also if the content is fairly static, most modern editors will allow you to search / replace in multiple files, there should be no reason to use gulp for what you are describing.

That being said try [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject)

Comment: this is for a project build, so I can have different index.html files for development, test, production etc.  So i want to manipulate the index.html file.  Something like gulp-inject.  Maybe I should just break out the html file into separate files like index.js.html which has all the js to be injected etc.